# How to bind value of btn REACT?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't understand why my value is the last value `data[i].Country` of  when it should not be.

```
for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var test = data[i].Country
        // All good \/
        console.log(test);

        const option = (
                                                           // here is the bug \/                                               
            <button className="btn" value={i} onClick={() => this.dataHandle(test)} >{test}</button>
        );
}
```

The `{test}` between `>{test}</button>` is good. The first `console.log(test)` is good.
Only the on in `() => this.dataHandle(test)` doesn't work.

```
dataHandle (country) {
    console.log(country);
}
```

Any idea why it as that behavior  ?

I tried many ways from internet but none of theme have worked :/

EDIT: Sorry I made a mistake when I pasted the code

Comment: You're passing the value of `test` as the *first* argument to `this.dataHandle()`. So wouldn't the country be in `a` instead of in `country`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to pass the current value = {i} as a in your datahandle.

```
for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var test = data[i].Country
        // All good \/
        console.log(test);

        const option = (
                                                           // Maybe this \/                                               
            <button className="btn" value={i} onClick={(e) => this.dataHandle(e.currentTarget, test)} >{test}</button>
        );
}

dataHandle (country) {
    country = country.textContent
}
```

Comment: The current value or the content value anything of them is good. Thanks

Comment: Okay. target or currentTarget. Do Accept the answer as correct. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to pass `event` to the function, you can do like below:

```
(e) => this.dataHandle(e, test)
```

Then in your function, you can access any property of `event`:

```
dataHandle (evt, country) {
    console.log(evt.target.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here isn't with React, instead it is a result of a JS mechanic called hoisting. When you declare a `var` in a function, it will be done at the start of the function. So these two function below are identical.

```
function a(){
  //Do something
  var value=5;
}

function b(){
  var value;
  //Do something
  value=5;
}
```

As such, your `test` variable is scoped *outside* the loop and will be changed when the callback is invoked.

There are two ways to fix this, either you use `let` or `const`, or you can use a callback factory

```
for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const test = data[i].Country
    console.log(test);

    const option = (
        <button className="btn" value={i} onClick={() => this.dataHandle(test)} >{test}</button>
    );
}
```

-- OR --

```
function createCallback(parameter){
  return function(){
    this.dataHandle(parameter);
  }
}
for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var test = data[i].Country

    const option = (
        <button className="btn" value={i} onClick={createCallback(test)} >{test}</button>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you call the `dataHandle` function with only one argument, but I can see it requires two. So that's why you have there undefined.